# How do I get the total size of all added files in Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Is there any method or event that can be called in dropzone.js to get the total size of all added files?

I have been able to get the size of each file with this code:

```
this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
        var fileSizes = file.size;
        $('.att-filesize').html(fileSizes).append(' Bytes');

});
```